# Getting HTML Form into PDF with jsPDF

Tags: jquery, html, forms, pdf, jspdf

I have a form that users will be filling in partially. Once they have made all their selections I want to render the page as is to PDF and then have it sent as email. I just can't seem to wrap my head around the tutorials and examples for it. Currently I have jquery and jspdf referenced in my head section

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

And this is my current function script - basically what's outlined in dozens of pages on here and elsewhere

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
   var specialElementHandlers = {
     '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
       return true;
    }
 };
 $('#cmd').click(function () {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
     doc.fromHTML($('#target').html(), 15, 15, {
      'width': 170,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
      });
    });
      doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Next I start my form and have a DIV containing the entire page that I want rendered

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<div id="target">
```

Followed by all the form inputs, then I close the DIV and have the button that should generate the PDF

```
</div>
<p>
<button id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I get nothing. No matter what I've done. The most I've gotten playing around with it is a blank page but  no content.  Any help steering me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This snippet seems to work but not sure if this is what you want. I corrected the syntax and moved the `doc` variable inside the click function.

As for the empty PDF issue, https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/130 and https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/270 might help.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    $('#cmd').click(function() {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.fromHTML($('#target').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div id="target">
        <input type="text" value="Nishant"/>
        </div>
        <p>
            <button id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That does make it create the PDF but yes it's blank. I'll have to start digging around with html2canvas or rasterizeHTML and see if I can make it work. Originally I was going to try and merge the original PDF with the POST values but after some reading I thought it would be easier or more efficient to do it this way.

Comment: There are server side solutions like wkhtmltopdf, weasyprint etc. There is also Prince XML and PDF Reactor if you want licensed ones.

Comment: I've seen those in many posts as well. The downside to all this is of course that I'm not a programmer and I'm having to cobble this together and reverse engineer it from examples, which I somehow manage to do most of the time. So far this has been more than I can handle. The unfortunate side effect of being a catch-all IT guy who has to go from installing equipment one day to rewriting all the web forms the next.